# How do I attach image to only one side of cube in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have script in three.js that makes my cube face the mouse of user, using `rotation.X` and `rotation.Y` It works just fine.

HTML:

```
<body>
<canvas id="webglcanvas" style="border: none;" width="1920" height="900">       </canvas>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var pageheight, pagewidth, widthpercentage, heightpercentage, specialW, specialH, radsX, radsY;

function animate() {
    cube.rotation.y = radsY;
    cube.rotation.x = radsX;
}

function run() {
requestAnimationFrame(function() { run(); });

// render the scene
renderer.render( scene, camera);
// spin the cube
animate();
}

$(document).ready(function() {

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    pageheight = $(document).height();
    pagewidth = $(document).width();
    widthpercentage = e.pageX / pagewidth;
    heightpercentage = e.pageY / pageheight;
    specialW = (widthpercentage * 180 - 90);
    specialH = (heightpercentage * 180 - 90);

    function toRadians(degrees) {
        radians = degrees * (Math.PI /180);
        return radians;
    }
    radsX = toRadians(specialH);
    radsY = toRadians(specialW);
});

    var canvas = document.getElementById("webglcanvas");

    // Create the Three.js render and attach it to our canvas 
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: canvas, antialias: true });

    // set the viewport size
    renderer.setSize(canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Create a new Three.js scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Add a camera so we can view the scene
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, canvas.width / canvas.height, 1, 4000 );
    scene.add(camera);

    // Create a texture-mapped cube and add it to the scene
    // First, create the texture map
    var mapUrl = "css/images/webgl-logo-256.jpg";
    var map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(mapUrl);

    // Now, create a Basic material; pass in the map
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map:map });

    // Create the cube geometry
    var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(4, 4, 1);

    // And put the geometry and material together into a mesh
    cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    // Move the mesh back from the camera and tilt it toward the viewer
    cube.position.z = -8;
    cube.rotation.x = Math.PI / 5;
    cube.rotation.y = Math.PI / 5;

    // Finally, add the mesh to our scene
    scene.add( cube );

    // Run the run loop
    run();

}
);
```

The only thing is I'm not sure how to attach an Image only to the front side of the cube and just leave all the other sides blank(white). I'm open to any suggestions, Thanks.